# Oracle update with join syntax not working

Tags: sql, sql-update

This is my working query in MS Access...

```
UPDATE Caxnode AS A INNER JOIN Caxnode AS B ON A.node_alias = B.node_alias 
SET A.partition_Type = 'LDOM', A.node_mode = 'LOGICAL', A.host_id = b.host_id, A.num_of_proc = b.num_of_proc 
WHERE (((A.node_mode)='virtual' Or (A.node_mode)='regular') AND ((B.partition_Type)='LDOM'));
```

This doesn't work in Oracle, I googled and read that update doesn't work with inner join in Oracle..

Can someone please help me translate this query to work on Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

JOIN in Update is a MS proprietary extension to UPDATE. From Googling [Oracle Update Syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm), I believe you can write it as:

```
UPDATE Caxnode AS A
SET (partition_Type, node_mode, host_id, num_of_proc)
= (select 'LDOM', 'LOGICAL', host_id, num_of_proc from Caxnode B where A.node_alias = B.node_alias and B.partition_Type='LDOM')
WHERE A.node_mode='virtual' Or A.node_mode='regular'
```

This syntax does ensure that if there are multiple rows on the B side, you'll get an error, whereas in Access/SQL Server, it will silently just pick one of the rows at random.

Comment: Not only MS. mysql also supports `JOIN` in `UPDATE`s

Comment: @zerkms - as an aside, what does mysql do if multiple rows in the non-updating table match a single row in the updating table?

Comment: doesn't matter how many rows matched in the **joined** table. If at least one row matches, then the according related row in the "main" table will be updated. In other words: `JOIN` in this case acts like an additional criteria, like `WHERE` (but related to another table).